# What is the proper first version? 0.1.0 or 0.0.1 or anything else?

Tags: version, open-source, semantic-versioning

How do you name the initial version? Could you tell the proper version of the first version?

Here is my candidates.

Way1

```
Start => 0.1.0 => 0.1.1 => 0.1.2
      => 0.2.0 => 0.2.2 => 0.2.3
      ...
      => 0.10.0
      ...
      => 1.0.0
```

or

Way2

```
Start => 0.0.1 => 0.0.2
      => 0.1.0 => 0.1.2 => 0.1.3
      ...
      => 0.10.0
      ...
      => 1.0.0
```

What is the best practice of naming version?

Comment: I know SemVer recommends `0.1.0`, but since `1.0.0` is the first public release, why not `0.0.0` for the initial version (it is a valid SemVer)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's your call, but the Semantic Versioning Standard [recommends 0.1.0](https://semver.org/):

> The simplest thing to do is start your initial development release at 0.1.0 and then increment the minor version for each subsequent release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one.
When I started Android Developent, I found that Android Studio used the first version of an app as `1` in the gradle files.

If you want to just know it generally, I recommend using `1.0` or `1` directly

Answer (score 0):

---

I think it should start at 0.1.0 and then at the main release, it goes to Version 1.0.0

Comment: Agreed, this makes logical sense, especially for a brand-new project with bearly any features in it! I use "Major.Feature.Patch" style versioning, and I always start with just a feature before calling it a full release.

See Also:
https://onlinecommunityhub.nl/nl/best-practice/semantic-versioning-what-s-in-a-number#:~:text=0.1.0%20is%20a%20work,is%20the%20first%20feature%20release.

Answer (score 0):

Technique:

```
Starts at 0.1,0 -> 0.1.1 ;sin (0.1.1) = 0.1.2
0.1.2 (1.7.0 -> cos:1(sin) = 0.5.0
0.2.5 (17.0) * 1.0.0 (sin):cos(0.1.0):e^ (0.1.0) = 
0.0.0 0.1.0(sin):1(cos)0.1.1{0p,0p,0p}*1(sin) = 1.8.0
0.1.6:(1.0.0)^sin{0p0p0p},sin= 0.9.0 0.7.0 /(sin){0p (0.1.0 }sin,[sin],10^(sin)= 1.0.0 sin(0p0p0p):0.1.1(sin:###) atan(0p0p0p) + (1.0.0)cos5(ERR110) = ERR150
```

Comment: 0.1.0 version is a oldest version in MCPE in THIS version There was ALMOST NOTHING

Comment: Please provide a description to why this technique works